# Using Login View Controller with ASIHttpRequest and Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, asihttprequest, storyboard

OK, I am building an application that will be using ASIHttpRequest in several places to either get JSON data from a web service or will be posting to a web service.  I have it working, but really don't like having several instantiations of the request object sprinkled around the different view controllers (Login view controller, a tableview controller, and a detail view controller.  I would like to move all my ASIHttpRequest methods to one class and just get back a dictionary of values that came back from the web service.  The problem with this is that the delegate methods don't return that I need to have returned.

What would be some suggestions on how I can consolidate all the methods that will create an HTTPRequest and return values when the request is finished.

I can post code if need be, but this is really more of a general question and not a specific issue.  If there are any tutorials on how this should be done, I would appreciate it.  I want my code to be efficient and pretty :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is going to be asynchronousity.  I'm not sure what you mean by consolidate, but you can have a singleton (you can just use your app delegate) to call the requests.  So you would do something like this:

```
[(MyAppDelegateClass *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate doLoginStuff:(NSDictionary *)params delegate:self];
```

If you're doing all this asynchronously, you can't just call this method and have it return something.  You'll be stuck with having some sort of callback to your view controller, which is the way ASI works out of the box essentially.  At best, you can minimize the code to generate the request and set any repetitive properties.

I'm not sure what you mean by having the instantiations floating throughout. If it's memory you're worried about, it would be no different reusing the same object. ASI typically uses an autoreleased request, so it would be the same as creating it in a "consolidated" method.  If it's just clean code, I would do a singleton way and maybe make a shortcut c-based method call in some type of Utilities class that you create and import in with your prefix file.  But again, you need the callback methods in your view controller so it doesn't get too much cleaner than it already is meant to work. I share your pain though.

When any request comes back, I almost always have a method that parses the results. Typically I'm only working with one type of web service, so have a method that parses the results and (also logs it to NSLog for debugging purposes) also gives me back an NSDictionary or NSArray.